# How to initialize static constant member using function

Tags: c++, linux, static, constants

In a very simplified case, I have the following setup in which, I simply want to initialize a constant static member(of class foo) from functions of class A (singleton and instance are unrelated to this question):

```
class A
{
public:

    static A instance;
    A & getInstance() { return instance; }
    int i(){ return 10;}
    int j(){ return 20;}
};

class foo {
public:

    static const int ii = A::getInstance().i() * A::getInstance().j(); 
};
const int foo::ii;

int main()
{
    foo f;
    return 1;
}
```

the aim is to initialize member ii using some function as above. but it generates the following error:

```
$ c++ static_constant.cpp 
static_constant.cpp:14:30: error: ‘A::getInstance()’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:42: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:44: error: ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:46: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:53: error: ‘A::getInstance()’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:65: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:67: error: ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
static_constant.cpp:14:69: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

could you please help me out? will Appreciate it.

Comment: see the comment on this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/407753/720176

Comment: Don't really see a reason for the downvote. @anDroider: Also don't get, what the linked comment has to do with the question. Can you explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues with the code, but here's a full compilable sample:

```
class A
{
public:

    static A instance;
    static A & getInstance() { return instance; }
    int i(){ return 10;}
    int j(){ return 20;}
};

class foo {
public:

    static const int ii;
};
const int foo::ii = A::getInstance().i() * A::getInstance().j(); 
A A::instance;
```

Comment: As a side note: 1. Singleton classes should have a private constructor. 2. The recommended way I know to instantiate the singleton object is **inside** the getInstance() method: `static A & getInstance() { static A theInstance; return theInstance; }`

Comment: @g-makulik not to mention using singleton in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getInstance` as a static function, but it's not declared `static`.

Change the declaration of `getInstance`:

```
static A & getInstance() { return instance; }
```